# HTML center list items on second line

Tags: html, css

With a simple html list like in the example below, how do I get the list items to center when it goes onto a second line?

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>

.container{max-width:500px;}
li{display:block;float:left;background:grey;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hzazvwte/

When the container is shrunk and the menu items start dropping into the line below, I would like them to be centered.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remove float, set `text-align: center;` to the container, `inline-block` to items, reset margin / padding and eliminate white spacing between elements.

```
.container {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* float: left; */
    background: grey;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzazvwte/4/

Comment: Yeah float left was problem one here, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the text in the li items?

```
.container{max-width:300px;}

li{
  display:block;
  float:left;
  background:grey;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```